# How to run "uniroot" several times to find intersection point of two functions

Tags: r, function, intersection, solver

I'm trying to run the function "uniroot" of the package "rootSolve" to find the intersection point of two function. My code is below:

```
g1 <- function(x,y){x^2/y^2}
f1 <- function(x, y){ x^2-3*y+g1(x)}
f2 <- function(x, z){ 4*z-x^2 } 
f <- function(x, y, z){ 
x^2-3*y-(4*z-x^2) 
} 

z <- 5; 
y <- 3 

rr=uniroot(f=f, y=y, z=z, interval=c(0,10))$root 
rr
```

The problem is when z and y are vectors with more than one elements, for example:

```
z <- c(1, 2, 3) 
y <- c(3, 4, 5) 

rr=uniroot(f=f, y=y, z=z, interval=c(0,10))$root
```

**The compute show this message:**

```
 f() values at end points not of opposite sign 
In addition: Warning messages: 
1: In if (is.na(f.lower)) stop("f.lower = f(lower) is NA") : 
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used 
2: In if (is.na(f.upper)) stop("f.upper = f(upper) is NA") : 
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What's the role of `f1`, `f2` and `g1`, all of which you never use? BTW, `uniroot` finds the intersection of a function of one variable with the x axis. Why `y` and `z` have multiple values? Do you want the intersection of more than one curve with the x axis? Are you aware that your function must return values of opposite sign at the end points? Please, clarify what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Actually my code will receive a lot of data of air temperature, relative humidity and soil moisture for evapotranspiration modelling, so I'm using a generic example to try and fix my real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `uniroot.all` in the package `rootSolve`. It's methodology can give you more than one answer. Then solve your equation to make sure you get the good value.